# Python: Use Variable in mulit-line string

Tags: python, string, smtplib, multilinestring

i have two variables:

```
subject = 'this is the subject'
body = 'this is the content'
```

For sending this per e-mail with smtplib i have my message variable as an multi line string. But the .format() method doesn't work. Has anybody an idea to solve this?

The message String:

```
    message = """\
    Subject: (variable subject)


    (variable content)"""
```

Comment: "But the .format() method doesn't work." yes it does. What did you try exactly? Please *always* include a [mcve]

Comment: `(variable subject)` isn't the right format for `str.format`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an f string for simplicity:

```
message = f"""
    Subject: {subject}


    {body}"""
```

Heres the right way to use `format()`:

```
message = """
subject = {}


{}
""".format(subject, body)
```

to use format, place `{}` where your variables need to be added and then declare `.format()` with a ***sequential*** list of the variables you want those `{}`'s to be replaced with

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it does but I think this is a bit more beginner-friendly and It'deasier to use :^)

Comment: Can you add it at the bottom as an alternative method for python<3.6?

Comment: IMO `.format` is more verbose and straightforward; a beginner can more easily grasp the concept of it. However `f-strings` are definitely easier to use.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`>>> subject = 'this is the subject'` 
                                                                                   `>>> body = 'this is the content'`         
                                                                                     `>>> message = '''\`  
                                                                                                          `... Subject: {subject}`  
                                                                                                       `...`    
                                                                                                                       `... {body}\`                      
                                                                                             `... '''.format(subject=subject, body=body)`   
                                                                                 `>>> print(message)`            
                                                                                                `Subject: this is the subject`     
                                                                                                                                                                                                                     `this is the content`

[image: Try this]

Comment: if anyone need to use braces(curly brackets) in the mutliline string.
use `{{` for `{`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure, what you are referring to, but this is my best guess:

```
message = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format(subject,body)
```

Answer (score 0):

@juanpa.arrivillaga

My Try:

```
message = """\
    Subject: {.format(subject)}


    Python test"""
```

Comment: Look at my answer below to see the correct way to use that, its actually much simpler!